# ImageResizer Focus Point

Tags: c#, .net, imageresizer

Problem: I am attempting to crop an image using any specific point on the image as a center point (focus point) for the crop. It should not include whitespace. Saved image should mimic this:

http://jonom.github.io/jquery-focuspoint/demos/helper/index.html.

I have been using ImageResizer's auto crop function until now. I know it allows you to specify a crop rectangle (but this would require me to do the calculations myself on where to crop. Is this functionality available in ImageResizer? Is there maybe an alternate way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Can you add a [plugin](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/croparound)? (Even if that isn't exactly what you want, you could maybe write one yourself...)

Comment: I could do it myself, but was looking to see if this functionality is already inbuilt, as there isn't much documentation available even on their own site.

Comment: The [full list of commands](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/reference) doesn't seem to do what you want out of the box, no.

Comment: That plugin lets me specify the rectangle to crop, but doesn't exactly meet all my requirements. But yes i will probably have to write my own

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the CropAround plugin: http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/croparound

If it doesn't do what you need, you could copy/modify it: https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/e7d2a5a47b9301c4c3b3b863716946c4b58b5ec7/Plugins/Faces/CropAroundPlugin.cs